# How to make DNS Server return different answers based on network availability?

Tags: bind, internal-dns, dns-zone

I Have a Bind9 docker container acting as the DNS Server of my network, I want this behavior when bind9 is asked about `example.com`:

```
If (Network is available):
  ask from 8.8.8.8 about example.com
If (Network is not available):
   return 172.16.2.2 as example.com
```

In other words I want bind9 to forward dns queries for `example.com` to `8.8.8.8` and if network is not available I want it to fallback to my local zone.

So far I have created a zone in my `named.conf` like this:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    forward first;
    max-zone-ttl 1;
    forwarders {
     8.8.8.8;
   }; 
   file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};
```

But it always returns the Ip in the local zone file (`172.16.2.2`). Isn't bind9 supposed to forward my requests first and then fallback to local zone?

Comment: `Isn't bind9 supposed to forward my requests first and then fallback to local zone?` No. This isn't a forum for "stuff I just made up".

Comment: @GregAskew ChatGPT told me this! I guess it's one of the hallucinations it makes!

Comment: This isn't a forum for shopping around broken AI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not. Also, you realize that - it does not matter because downstream caching.

DNS side load balancing of any kinds has not worked for - well, since DNS was invented.

Btw:

> isn't bind9 supposed to forward my requests first and then fallback
> to local zone?

WTF? Does the documentation not show EXACTLY the opposite? Why would it use a forwarder - it if has itself authoritative information (i.e. the entry is in it's zone file)?

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: Not use DNS for what it is not supposed to do. Hire a competent admin. The solution depends on WHAT you want to do with it - is this for HTTP? For that?